# jmeter log shows an error jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser

Tags: jmeter

I have run testplan.jmx (Jmeter file) file from docker jmeter using one .sh run script, after running getting below error 
ERROR - jmeter.protocol.http.sampler.HTTPSamplerBase: Cannot find .className property for htmlParser, ensure you set property:'htmlParser.className'
Please suggest what can be done to resolve the issue? it would really helpful if any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your JMeter installation is corrupt, try re-installing the latest version of JMeter (JMeter 3.1 as of now), you can get it from JMeter Downloads page.

---

As a workaround try adding the following line to *user.properties* file:

```
htmlParser.className=org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser
```

or alternatively pass it through `-J` command-line argument like:

```
jmeter -JhtmlParser.className=org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.parser.LagartoBasedHtmlParser -n -t ....
```

References:

- [Bug 55632 - Have a new implementation of htmlParser for embedded resources parsing with better performances](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=55632)
- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization)